# React router - pass api data to the linked component to open with a new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I am struggling to understand to design the routing here. For example -

```
array.map((each)=>(
         <Link to="details/${each.id}"> <Card props={each}/> </Link>
    ))
```

by clicking on these cards, the skeleton of detailed page will open but how am i going to pass some data related to the card to the new page? I want to send some **api data** to new page related to each card or pass some **information** to call api related to that card after switching to that new component page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sending Data with Route transition

You can send state along with the route transition using a `Link`'s [to object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object).

> **to: object**
>
> An object that can have any of the following properties:
>
> - pathname: A string representing the path to link to.
> - search: A string representation of query parameters.
> - hash: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.
> - ***state: State to persist to the location.*** <-- you need this

```
array.map((each)=>(
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: `details/${each.id}`,
      state: {
        // whatever you need to send with the route transition
      },
    }}
  >
    <Card props={each}/>
  </Link>
))
```

## Receiving the Route State

You've a few options.

1. Easiest and more common way now with using the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) React hook in functional components.

   ```
   const { state } = useLocation();
   ```
2. Decorating a component with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component and inject [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

   If your component is decorated with `withRouter` it will have the current route props injected as props.

   ```
    export default withRouter(EachComponent);
   ```

   Access `state` from the `location` prop.

   ```
    const { state } = this.props.location;
   ```
3. Directly render by a `Route` component and receive the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

   If your component is rendered directly by a `Route` it will have the route props passed to it.

   ```
    <Route path="/details/:id" component={EachComponent} />
   ```

   Access `state` from the `location` prop.

   ```
    const { state } = this.props.location;
   ```

**Note:** Route state is transient, meaning it only exists during the transition from one route to the next. If you navigate directly to a receiving route it won't have the state because it didn't use the transition from the route providing the state.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data with [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) using **location state** or **search** (or query params):

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: '/path/to/my/component',
    search: 'id=123&name=foo',
    state: { data: 111 },
  }}
>
  Click Me
</Link>
```

And to retrieve in the `MyComponent` (e.g.using hooks):

```
const location = useLocation()
const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search)

console.log(location.state)
console.log(query.get('id'))
console.log(query.get('name'))
```

PS: You can also make a custom hook - [`useQuery`](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) for query params.

But be aware that if you open path - `/path/to/my/component` directly in the browser by typing it manually, there will be no location state or query params.

And [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is not supported in Internet Explorer, if you need to support IE as well, you can use some package like [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string).