# Passing data from parent component to child component on button click

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-props, react-functional-component

I am new to React. What I am trying to achieve is to render a new component when a button is clicked in the parent component and pass some data from parent to child. I am able to navigate from parent to child but I am unable to pass data. Below is the simplified version of my code.
My parent component - Posts.js

```
    const Posts = (props) => {
      const { posts, loading } = props;
      var nameArray = posts.map(function (el) {
        return el.kiosk_name;
      });
      console.log(nameArray);
      if (loading) {
        return <h2>Loading All Kiosks....</h2>;
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <Link to={`/kiosks/addkiosk`}>
            <button className="AddBtn" onClick={nameArray}>ADD</button>
          </Link>
)}
```

Child component - AddKiosk.js

```
export const AddKiosk = (props) => {
  const { nameArray } = props;
  console.log(nameArray);
}
```

I am trying to pass the **nameArray** from **onClick** but the console log of AddKiosk shows - **Undefined**. Please let me know where am I going wrong. Sorry if my question is very trivial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using react-router-dom and when you click on `ADD` button, it takes you to URL `/kiosks/addkiosk` and renders the `AddKiosk` component.

#### Expected:

You want to send `nameArray` data to `AddKiosk` component.

#### Solution:

You can pass some data as **location state** using `Link`'s [to](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object) prop. You may read [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610677/2873538).

### Code

```
const Posts = (props) => {
  const { posts, loading } = props
  var nameArray = posts.map(function (el) {
    return el.kiosk_name
  })
  console.log(nameArray)

  if (loading) {
    return <h2>Loading All Kiosks....</h2>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={{
        pathname: `/kiosks/addkiosk`,
        state: nameArray // HERE, passing data using Link
      }}>
        <button className="AddBtn">
          ADD
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export const AddKiosk = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  console.log(location.state) // HERE, it will print data
  return <>i am AddKiosk</>
}
```